# c# An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property Android.Widget.TabHost.NewTabSpec(string)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying ot create an app which should include some tabs for navigation and I followed a walkthrough, adding my own details, but I get one error twice in the final step.

The walkthrough I used was this: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/tab_layout/Walkthrough_Creating_a_tabbed_ui/

I didn't use the walkthrough project, but started my own project.

The errors appear in line 31 and 36.

Also, I'm very much a beginner at this.

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace AppTest1
{
    [Activity (Label = "Pathfinder Combat Companion", MainLauncher = true, Icon =    "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        CreateTab(typeof(Combat_Statistics), "combat_stats", "Combat Statistics", Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_whats_on);
        CreateTab(typeof(ConditionsBuffs), "condi_buffs", "Consitions/Buffs", Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_speakers);
        CreateTab(typeof(Skills), "skills", "Skills", Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_sessions);
        CreateTab(typeof(Spellbook), "spellbook", "Spellbook", Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_my_schedule);
    }
    private void CreateTab(Type activityType, string tag, string label, int drawableId )
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, activityType);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        var spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec(tag);
        var drawableIcon = Resources.GetDrawable(drawableId);
        spec.SetIndicator(label, drawableIcon);
        spec.SetContent(intent);

        TabHost.AddTab(spec);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it means exactly what is written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I didn't use the walkthrough project, but started my own project.

Then carefully look at the differences.

You're inheriting from `Activity`, which doesn't have a `TabHost` property.

`TabActivity` does, so change your class to `public class MainActivity : TabActivity`. Or instantiate a `TabHost` yourself (if the API supports that).

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Although it doesn't operate properly, but that's a whole other question. 
I almost didn't get what you meant as you wrote "so change your class to public class MainActivity : Activit" instead of "so change your class to public class MainActivity : TabActivity"